# With Git how do I insert a modified file into the master branch

Tags: git, maven

I just have a master branch, I need to go back to an earlier tag to modify the `pom.xml` file and then release it to Maven Central. So I want to edit the file and then commit it, but if I do that and then swap back to the latest commit I assume I will see that modified file as the latest file when I do `git checkout` back to HEAD, which would be wrong.

So how do I insert a modified file into the master branch?

```
git checkout tag/v2.2.5
edit pom.xml
# commit somehow, and push to remote
mvn release
git checkout
```

At this point, the current code should look the same as it did to start with.

Comment: You don't ("insert a file into a branch", that is). You *add commits* to a branch, but to do so, you must have the branch checked out. Checking out a tag isn't necessarily wrong as a *starting point* but once you've done that, you would then have to create a *new* branch. Given that you're using Maven, which has its own ways of dealing with these things, I can't provide a full answer, but you're definitely thinking about this in the wrong way: at the Git level, you want to be on the branch you want to add commits to.

Comment: If you then need some old version of a file, you extract that one old version of that one file, e.g., `git show tag/v2.2.5:pom.xml > pom.xml` in a sh/bash style shell, or `git restore -SW --source tag/v2.2.pom.xml` in any CLI, etc.

Comment: Forget about maven that was just to give context, but i dont use brabches usually and even when a branch is created a pull requesr merges that into master. so even if i create a branch with the one file change how do i then merge it into master at the commit linked  to the tag rather than just at latest commit.

Comment: You don't. A tag means *that commit*. You should never make it mean "*that* commit no wait I mean some other commit!" as you'll mess up everyone else who's already picked it up and already mean *that* commit. After you make a new commit and get it into a *branch*, make a *new tag* for the new commit.

Comment: okay so if I do as you say I never merge it back into master it just sits on this new branch, is that what you are saying ?

Comment: That's an option. You would do that sort of thing if, for instance, you need a release branch for holding updates to `v2.2.x`: you had `v2.2.5` and now you will have `v2.2.6`, so the release branch is `release-2.2`, or something along those lines.

Comment: The Maven folks have a whole ecosystem dedicated to this sort of thing, if I understand correctly. There are a lot of competing schemes to handle Semantic Versioning, no matter what version control system you use to store your commits.

Comment: I wished I hadnt mentioned maven because it has nothing to do with this problem. Thanks for your attempted help but I think one of us is completely missing something because I cant understand why it is only possible to add commits to the tip of the MASTER branch, and never to an earlier point.

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can only add commits at the current point of a branch. Otherwise, you need to create a new branch. That is just how git works.

Comment: I create a new branch,  fine and commit to that, but once i have done that is there no way to merge into an earlier point i the master branch ?

Comment: No. You cannot merge into earlier points of branches. (This is probably not completely true because technically, you can rewrite history in git, but that will probably be a nightmare for everyone else using the master branch at the moment).

Comment: ok, so I have a master branch showing the evolution of the project with tags indicating new versions as they are released, but because there is a mistake with one of those earlier versions the only way i can fix it is to make a new branch at the commit where the tag was added and make the fix on that branch, and have to keep that branch forever just for this fix. Then I suppose I would delete the existing tag and move it to this branch for this version

Comment: The point of history is to remember *everything, including the mistakes*. That way we don't repeat the mistakes tomorrow. (Note: I've expanded from mere "Git commit history" to "all of human history": we study why Rome fell, or which Chinese dynasties were good for their people, for the same kinds of reasons.) Going back to Git, a tag name is "some point in history" and a branch name is "my latest".

Comment: im not trying to erase any mistakes Im just trying to fix a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay from the comments it seems is not possible, so as the purpose was to make a change to the build file so that I could just deploy the builds to the Maven repository I did the following instead:

```
git checkout tag/v2.2.5
edit pom.xml
mvn clean deploy -Prelease
git reset --hard
git checkout master
```

So I used git to go to the right place and make the edit, I did the build and then just discarded the edit.